# Why does RemoteTokenServices call the UAA frequently?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, single-sign-on, spring-security-oauth2

There are a Microservices that is secured by Spring Security OAuth2. The grant type in `Authorization_code`. The list of apps are:

1- Zuul Gateway as OAuth2 client.

2- UAA(Authorization Server).

3- 10 micros as Resource servers that are backed behind Zuul.

4- TokenStore is JdbcTokenStore.

Every thing is working correctly as expected.

In the Resource Servers because of incompatible between these application as Micro and the problem of Serialization and DeSerialization, there is `RemoteTokenServices` instead of `DefaultTokenServices` for retrieving the UserInfo, so into any Resource Server is:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      user-info-uri: http://localhost:9191/uaa/user
```

There is **a vital question** for me, **why each Resource Server calls the UAA for any request**?(To see the source code [click me](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/RemoteTokenServices.java))Is not it better that it calls the UAA as soon as receiving first request of each token and the Principal is stored into Resource Server for the next request  of that token until it is not required to call the UAA again.

In other hand each Resource Server calls only the UAA as soon as receiving first request for any distinct token and it is used for  thier next requests?

Comment: Do you want to know what other ways are possible without asking the authorization server (for example JWT)? Or do you want to know how to customize `RemoteTokenServices` to cache the users?

Comment: I want to customize 'RemoteTokenServices'. Is it possible or not?

Comment: You could implement a custom class extending `RemoteTokenServices` and cache the user.

Comment: Is there a sample to show?

Comment: No, you have to do you it on your own.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your last comment. Could you rephrase it?